# How to override a Insert module tpl file?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to override a .tpl file from the Insert module in my D7 theme.

I copied the file from sites/all/modules/insert/templates/image-insert-image.tpl.php to sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/image-insert-image.tpl.php.  I then made an edit to the copy in my theme directory and cleared cache.  I'm not seeing the change reflected when I insert an image using the module.

Just to make sure I had the correct file, I made the same edit to the original the file in the module directory and that worked.  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the admin theme when editing/adding content instead of the usual public facing one? Eg, are you putting the override in the correct theme because overriding it in the module (wrong of course) would override all themes.

Comment: Also, you have to clear the cache for new templates to be registered.

Comment: Well, yes, I am using an admin theme to create content.  Now I understand why putting the override in my public theme wouldn't do anything.  Then how can I do what I need to do, which is to override the template in my admin theme?  Thank you for taking the time to answer.